# Raw-data thread-safe buffer for a large file

Tags: c++, multithreading, bigdata

I have a very big binary file (~200GB) that contains serialized objects. The iterative algorithm reads this file multiple times (100-200 times) and processes all records independently.

The order in which all stored objects will be processed is not important. That allows to parallelize the algorithm. So, the bottleneck here is reading from file.

What is the fastest way to read the raw data from file and make it readable by many threads?

Note: since reading from disk is much slower than processing objects, even deserialization should be moved to workers. So I need a raw data storage which is thread-safe.

Comment: The solution might depend on the used operating system. Are you interested in a solution for a specific operating system? Or should the solution be independent of OS?

Comment: Does all the objects i.e records gets changed every time?

Comment: @nosid It is absolutely OK if the solution is Unix-specific.

Comment: @rakib No, the file is read-obly

Answer (score 0):

If processing via one CPU consumes data faster than the IO to the storage can provide it, threads won't give you any advantage. Actually, the OS is pretty good at reading ahead, and using DMA it does so concurrently, so it will already have things cached when you return to retrieve more.

That said, you could just memory-map the file, assuming it fits into your process space, and then start worker threads on parts of the file. Alternatively, with 32 bit addresses, use one sliding window on the memory-mapped file for each worker. This will make reasonably sure IO is saturated but it will also mess with the OS' readahead, so maybe it won't even gain you anything.